# finding number of children using size() in jquery

Tags: jquery, syntax

I have a jquery menu that has so many entries that it extends further than the length of the page. I want to get the number of entries in each menu section so I can use that to resize a padding div at the end of the page.

```
$('.hideMe').click(function(){ 
    alert( $(this).next('ul').children() );
});
```

So I want to find out the number of li tags under the ul tag.

```
<h3 class="hideMe">Items</h3>
    <ul class="myul">
        <li id="001" >
            <a href="products.php?item=001">Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li id="002" >
            <a href="products.php?item=002">Item 2</a>
        </li>   
        <li id="003" >
        <a href="products.php?item=003">Item 3</a>
        </li>
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this:

```
$(this).next('ul').find('li').length
```

?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".hideMe").click(function(){ 
    alert( $(this).next("ul").find("li").length);
});
```

But rather I'd do `$(this).next("ul").height()` to get the height right away.

Comment: hm. using height seems the best way to do this but as this height check happens when the menu is closed it returns 1. It gives the correct height when I click again on it, as then the menu is extended.

Comment: Why not first get the height and then close it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd agree with the answer provide by Staicu (And I've voted it up), but you need to consider whether the number of children is sufficient information for what you want to do.

Don't forget to allow for different monitor resolutions and the fact that the size (More specifically to your case - the height) of the browser window can change.

I'm not completely sure what role the 'padding div' plays in the overall layout - maybe a more detailed example would help us to understand.

Comment: just before the footer on the page I have a div:   
    <div id="pad"></div>
This div's height would then be resized to make the page longer and fit the v. long menu